# C++ why is iostream so huge

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm working on an embedded device (therefore we are linking static) and I was trying to include iostream

However simply by including iostream (not event instantiating any stream) it blasts my Flash.

The IOStream Header looks pretty innocent to me. It includes some extern definitions like

`extern istream cin;      /// Linked to standard input`

But since no stream is callend they should never be linked into the static bianry.

It has a static variable as well
`static ios_base::Init __ioinit;`

Since declared static this will be copied to every translation unit (however the RAM size is about 20 bytes, so that shouldn't be so big).

There are may virtual inline templates. But I was under the impression that no template will get compiled if its not instantiated.

So where does the huge flash amount come from over if iostream is included but not used?

Comment: I'd say try using `<cstdio>`

Comment: Embedded `iostream` is an oxymoron.

Comment: `iostream` has `cout`, `cin`, `cerr` which are all objects with static storage duration, these objects are allocated at program start and destroyed at program exit, even if they are not used. The question here is, would the compiler be allowed to optimize that away if they are not used, but as this could be considered as a side-effect it would guess it might not be allowed.

Comment: If you want to make sure that you get warned if you include a header that you don't use you could utilize [include-what-you-use](https://include-what-you-use.org/)

Comment: Hey thx for your answer. I think I'll go with <cstdio> :) But i don't get why cout, cin cerr are actually linked into the binary. Are they defined as volatile so that they can't get optimised out?. @t.niese does this work with gcc as well?

Comment: @JHeni include-what-you-use  is just a separate static analyzer, so you can run it on your code even you compile it with gcc (I have many projects that I compile with gcc, in combination with include-what-you-use, clang-tidy, and clang-format) . But I don't know much about embedded development, so I don't know if there are any other pitfalls due to that.

Comment: @JHeni I can't say for sure if `cout`, `cin` and `cerr` are really the actual reason, but that would is IMHO a plausible guess. It it is probably more that if you include iostream, that the link-time optimizer then does not remove the portions from the static lib that are related to it.

Comment: If you include `<iostream>` it puts the Schwarz Nifty Counter for `std::cin`, `std::cout`, and `std::cerr` initialization, which means you've pulled in all that machinery even if your code doesn't use them.  Your code should only include what it uses.

Comment: All versions of the C++ standard specify that standard streams (`std::cout`, `std::cin`, etc) are constructed before `main()` is called. Practically, if one or more compilation units `#include <iostream>`, implementations (compilers/libraries) typically include machinery to instantiate the objects in the executable  - essentially they assume that, if any compilation unit includes `<iostream>` that the standard streams are required.  Instantiating those objects means the implementation of the types (data and code, of which there is quite a bit) is also included in the executable.

Comment: @JHeni: With regard to "optimising out", you suspect `volatile` is involved. It's true that access to `volatile` objects cannot be optimised out. But the same also applies to I/O operations in the Standard Library, e.g. `std::cout << "Hello, world";`. Technically you could still optimise out `std::cout;` on its own, but who writes that?